# Can not redirect user after successful login

Tags: spring, jsf, spring-security

I m using primefaces and spring security
the method below inside my backing bean works well.It invokes user details service and authenticates or rejects login attempts.
My problem is with redirection. What is the proper way of redirecting a user to the desired page after auth? Currently I can see that the user is authenticated but still the login form is displayed.

```
public String login(){

    try{
        Authentication request = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(this.getUsername(), this.getPassword());
        Authentication result = authenticationManager.authenticate(request);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(result);
    }
    catch(Exception e){

        e.printStackTrace();
        return "incorrect";
    }
 return "correct"; 

}



<http auto-config="true">

     <intercept-url pattern="/web/*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
     <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />

     <form-login login-page="/web/login.xhtml" 
      default-target-url="/main.xhtml"
     always-use-default-target="true"     />

</http>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">

        <authentication-provider  user-service-ref="kullaniciDetayServisi" />

</authentication-manager>




</beans:beans>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <div align="center" style="">
        <h:form  id="loginFormId" prependId="false">
                <div id="loginFieldsPnlId">
                    <div id="loginFieldUsrContId">
                        <h:outputText id="outTxtUserNameId" value="Username: " name="outTxtUserNameNm"></h:outputText>
                        <h:inputText id="userName" required="true" value="#{loginBean.username}" requiredMessage="Please enter username"></h:inputText>
                        <h:outputLabel id="outLblUserNameId" for="userName" name="outLblUserNameNm"></h:outputLabel>
                    </div>
                    <div id="loginFieldPassContId">
                        <h:outputText id="outTxtPasswordId" value="Password: " name="outTxtPasswordNm"></h:outputText>
                        <h:inputSecret id="password"  required="true" value="#{loginBean.password}" requiredMessage="Please enter password" name="inTxtPasswordNm"></h:inputSecret>
                        <h:outputLabel id="outLblPasswordId" for="password" name="outLblPasswordNm"></h:outputLabel>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="loginBtnPanelId">
                    <h:commandButton id="btnLoginId" value="Login" action="#{loginBean.login}"  ajax="false"></h:commandButton>
                    <h:commandButton id="btnCancelId" value="Cancel" action="#{loginBean.cancel}"   immediate="true" update="loginFormId" ajax="false"></h:commandButton>
                </div>
        </h:form>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h:messages></h:messages>
    </div>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: How is this PrimeFaces related? Does it work with plain jsf?

Comment: it is the same with plain jsf. i added our login form. PF is the frontend library of the project

Comment: If it fails with plain JSF to I'll remove the PrimeFaces tag and please create an [mcve]

Comment: How is this question different from your previous one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34997908/spring-security-does-not-redirect-to-landing-page-after-succesful-login-via-jsf/

Comment: in this question i am not seeking fixes of a certain   problem rather i m looking for a proper way of redirecting

Comment: please help BalusC , i m broken into pieces

Comment: are you mapping the returned logical view `correct` and `incorrect` in controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to map the `correct` and `incorrect` path inside controller methods.

If I want to redirect than I might use

```
return "redirect:/correct/" + user.getUserName();
```

And handle this new request in a new controller method that map this new request.
or

```
return "redirect:/incorrect"
```

Return something like that from the controller method that handle login request.

or

Using proper navigation rules in `/web/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml` for JSF like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config version="2.2"
              xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">
    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/index.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>incorrect</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/failure.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>correct</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/sucess.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
</faces-config>
```

Comment: return "/main.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";  made the trick for me. Thank you Rohit.You made my day.

Comment: `<navigation-rule>
<from-view-id>/greeting.xhtml</from-view-id>
<navigation-case>
<from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
<to-view-id>/response.xhtml</to-view-id>
</navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>`
For JSF specific details look at this official [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-intro005.htm). Should not be using this trick. Should be handling event properly.

Comment: `redirect:` is a Spring MVC related artifact which cannot be used with JSF.

Comment: Spring MVC is a completely different thing. It is not equal to Spring.